# Can my mouse events work when the mouse is not locked while using PointerLockControls in React Three Fiber?

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I have a question regarding the following CodeSandbox project about PointerLockControls of the React Three Fiber library:

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-panini-k6f8wx?file=/src/App.js

In this sandbox example, when you click on the screen to lock the mouse (causing the mouse icon to disappear), you can hover over the boxes, by centering them on the screen. As a result, the mouseover event of the mesh is triggered, and the color of the box changes to pink.

However, I want the mousemove event to trigger even when my mouse is not locked. In other words, I want to move over the meshes with the mouse icon visible (when the mouse is not locked), and have them turn pink just like they do in the locked mouse mode. Unfortunately, this behavior doesn't currently work.

I've noticed that in tres.js (R3f of the Vue.js ecosystem), this functionality seems to work naturally. Mouse events are triggered even when the mouse is not locked. I assume this feature can be implemented in my R3f project as well, but I haven't been able to figure out how.

Comment: ps: I've achieved what i wanted by yomotsu's camera-controls library instead of the PointerLockControls.